# Передача данных на другие сцены

Tags: unity3d

ломаю голову на локализацией, а точнее о передаче данных переменной.
Мне нужно передать текст переменной на объект на другой сцене. DontDestroyOnLoad не подойдет, ибо нужно инициализировать объект на другой сцене. Через Find категорически не хочу. Последний вариант - это изменять префаб и по новой его создавать. Просто хочу знать нюансы.

```
[LocalizationTextAttribute("Play")]
public static string Play = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[А если PlayerPrefs использовать?](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

```
// в старой сцене сохраняете значение
    string strLastScene = "someString";
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("varName", strLastScene);
// в новой сцене извлекаете это значение:
// таким образом
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("varName"))
    {
      string strNextScene = PlayerPrefs.GetString("varName");
    }
// или таким образом
    string strNextScene = PlayerPrefs.GetString("varName", "defaultString");
```

Comment: все ваши способы подходят. Проблема лишь в инициализации объекта("public GameObject GO; // объект на сцене.

Comment: так у вас была задача инициализировать объект в новой сцене или передать этому объекту значение?

Comment: да, но объяснять я похоже не научился.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно восспользоваться паттерном [Singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton)
Пишете свой класс на этом паттерне, например, какой-нибудь менеджер локализации. Между загрузками сцены объект с таким "менеджером локализации" не удаляйте, а для получения каких-то данных из класса юзайте

```
"менеджер локализации".Instance.Метод()/Переменная...
```

Или же можно использовать статичный класс, тогда на сцену вообще его выносить не потребуется.

```
public static class RusLocalization
{
    public static string BUTTON_PLAY = "Играть";
    public static string GAME_TITLE = "Заголовок...";
}
```

А юзаем так:

```
private string Play = RusLocalization.BUTTON_PLAY;
```

Comment: Сказано же, DontDestroyOnLoad не использовать

Comment: дак синглтон можно использовать без "крепления на объект". ему необязательно быть в сцене. Да вот проблема остается в том, что приходится инициализировать объект через public в каждой сцене.

Comment: Если синглтон удалить между переходами со сцены на сцену - его нестатичные поля не сохранят своих значений.

Comment: Верно, поэтому я сохраняю их отдельно.